# Import statement in library definition does not seem to be executed

Tags: python, import, nameerror

I am having a problem that may be quite a basic thing, but as a Python learner I've been struggling with it for hours. The documentation has not provided me with an answer so far.

The problem is that an import statement included in a module does not seem to be executed when I import this module from a python script. What I have is as follows:

I have a file project.py (i.e. python library) that looks like this:

```
import datetime

class Project:
    """ This class is a container for project data """

    title        = ""
    manager      = ""
    date         = datetime.datetime.min

    def __init__( self, title="", manager="", date=datetime.datetime.min ):
    """ Init function with some defaults """

        self.title        = title
        self.manager      = manager
        self.date         = date
```

This library is later used in a script (`file.py`) that imports project, it starts like this:

```
import project

print datetime.datetime.min
```

The problem then arises when I try to execute this script with Python `file.py`. Python then complains with the folliwing NameError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 3, in <module>
    print datetime.datetime.min
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

This actually happens also if I try to make the same statements (`import` and `print`) directly from the Python shell.

Shouldn't the `datetime` module be automatically imported in the precise moment that I call `import project`?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `datetime` doesn't mean anything in your module, because you haven't bound that name to anything. Other modules won't affect your local namespace!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `datetime` module is only imported into the `project` namespace.  So you *could* access it as `project.datetime.datetime.min`, but really you should import it into your script directly.

Every symbol (name) that you create in your `project.py` file (like your `Project` class) ends up in the `project` namespace, which includes things you import from other modules.  This isn't as inefficient as it might seem however - the actual `datetime` module is still only imported once, no matter how many times you do it.  Every time you import it subsequent to the first one it's just importing the *names* into the current namespace, but not actually doing all the heavy lifting of reading and importing the module.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking of the `import` statement as roughly equivalent to:

```
project = __import__('project')
```

Effectively an `import` statement is simply an assignment to a variable. There may be some side effects as the module is loaded, but from inside your script all you see is a simple assignment to a name.

You can pull in all the names from a module using `from project import *`, but **don't do that** because it makes your code much more brittle and harder to maintain. Instead either just import the module or exactly the names you want.

So for your code something like:

```
import datetime
from project import Project
```

is the sort of thing you should be doing.

Comment: Telling a new python programmer that something very basic like `import` is equal to the super-internal-your-life-will-be-better-if-you-never-need-to-use-it `__import__` function seems counterproductive (using real pseudocode probably would have been better).

Comment: My point was that it is simply equivalent to something done in a magic function and a simple assignment. You can read `__import__` as '__some_internal_magic_that_you_dont_need_to_know_about__` if you prefer.

Comment: -0.0 ... It's NOT "super internal" (despite the quadruple underscores, it's documented along with the other non-internal not-deprecated built-in functions); OTOH it's definitely in the *pas devant les enfants* category.